# How do I get one model and post to another properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building an online store and I am currently working with 2 models. The `Shirt` model displays all the details about the t-shirt (photo, description, base price, sizes)which is currently on display for the user. The `Order` model is all the user selected items what size and what quantity. Currently, in the post method of my order controller, I have the following to display to the user the info coming from the shirt model:

```
[AuthLog(Roles="Registered Users, Administrators")]
public ActionResult Index(int? id, Shirt shirt)
{
    var result = (from s in db.Shirts where s.SiteActive == true select s).ToList();
    id = (from s in result select s.Id).First();
    var sCount = result.Count();
    ViewBag.TabTitle = null;
    ViewBag.ShirtSizeId = new SelectList(db.ShirtSizes, "Id", "Name");
    ViewBag.ShirtQuantityId = new SelectList(db.ShirtQuantities, "Id", "Name");
    if (sCount >= 1)
    {
        shirt = db.Shirts.Include(s => s.Files).SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
        var TabTitle = (from s in result select s.TabName).First();
        var TabContent = (from s in result select s.Caption).First();
        var TabPrice = (from s in result select s.Price).First();
        ViewBag.TabTitle = TabTitle;
        ViewBag.TabContent = TabContent;
        ViewBag.TabPrice = TabPrice;
    }

    return View(shirt);
}
```

And in the view I have

```
@model TShirtEmpAdmin.Models.Shirt
```

to be able to display the items for the shirt for sale. But I also need to post the user selected information `quantity` and `size` to the orders table. However, I cannot have 2 models in the view and I tried combining them into a view model like this:

```
public class ShirtOrderViewModel
{
    public virtual<Shirt> Shirts { get; set; }
    public virtual<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

but I the following error:

**Cannot implicitly convert type Model to ViewModel**

Comment: Did you updated your view's model to ShirtsOrderViewModel and return that type of object from your action?

Comment: Did you mean to create a list of shirts "List<Shirt>" or a virtual of Shirts? Same question applies to the Orders.

Comment: @AliBaig yes I did, that's what caused the error

Comment: @AlfMoh I was just trying to follow several examples here on Stack Overflow with bad, bad results...lol

Comment: @Skullomania I'm sure we can do it with your ShirtOrderViewModel. There must be some mismatching of types that's going on! But that is the right approach!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve what you intended is creating `viewmodel` suits to your objective. Your model in your view should be something like `@model TShirtEmpAdmin.Models.OrderViewModel` with definition like :

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items{ get; set; }        
}
```

One of your items is `Shirt`. If you have nothing than shirt in your items you can change `public List<Item> items{ get; set; }` to `public List<Shirt> shirts{ get; set; }`. and if no one  can order more than one shirt on order time you could change `public List<Shirt> shirts{ get; set; }` to `public Shirt shirt{ get; set; }`.